# Cannot perform aggreagate function on an expression

Tags: sql

Stuck on how to overcome the dreaded message that comes with the code below
What is the correct way to do this. I do not want to use an IN statement

```
select field1,
SUM(CASE
   WHEN Value IN(SELECT xx FROM yy Where zz)THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)field2
 group by field1
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please add example data and expected output.

Comment: correct your query, it missed "from" keyword, also try to provide a specific  query

Comment: first, this seems to be invalid sql.  Three is no From clause in outer query.  Where is the value of `field1` supposed to be coming from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many (most?  all?) databases do not allow subqueries in aggregation expressions.  The solution is usually to move the aggregation *inside* the subquery:

```
SELECT field1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yy Where zz AND t.value = xx ) as field2
FROM xx t
GROUP BY field1;
```

Note that this construct might not be exactly the same, in the event that multiple values match a single row.  In that case, you would want `count(distinct)` of something.

Answer (score 0):

as the query and question was not so clear so I'm not sure but I think if you comparing a value from your_table with yy table then use a `left join` from your table for such these queries in the question:

```
select t.field1,
 sum(
       case when y.xx is null then 0 else 1 end) field2
from your_table t left outer join yy y on t.value=y.xx
group by t.field1
```